# Getting Error 101 while installing supergfxctl

Tags: asus, 23.04

I did every thing they say [here](https://gitlab.com/asus-linux/supergfxctl) to install supergfxctl on [my laptop](https://www.amazon.ae/dp/B09RSWJW92) running Ubuntu 23.04 (dual boot with Windows 11) but I'm getting this error at the end:

```
make: *** [Makefile:77: build] Error 101
```

and this is the full output [here](https://justpaste.it/b4d22).
What is the problem and what can I do? I tried `cargo clean` but didn't work.